# specify location name if point intersects it MySQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0

I am using MySQL 8.0

I have two tables: location_table, rent_table

location_tables looks like:

```
location_name    polygon 
 A                BLOB
 B                BLOB 
 ...
```

polygon is POLYGON datatype.

rent_table looks like:

```
user_id    rent_time    rent_location   
   1           x           BLOB
   2           x           BLOB
  ...
```

where rent_location is POINT data type

for each row in rent_table I want to create a column that indicate which location_name it belongs to. If user_id rent_location intersects location_name = A new column would have A

It would look something like this:

```
user_id    rent_time    rent_location    location_name
   1           x           BLOB                A
   2           x           BLOB                B
  ...
```

Thanks in advance!

What I've tried:

I can do one by one by using

```
select *
     , st_intersects(A, Point(ST_X(work_location), ST_Y(work_location))) as location_A
     , st_intersects(B, Point(ST_X(work_location), ST_Y(work_location))) as location_B 
     , st_intersects(C, Point(ST_X(work_location), ST_Y(work_location))) as location_C
 from rent_table;
```

This works when I set A,B,C variable beforehand but I want to get location polygon directly from location_table.

I could use subquery like below:

```
select *
     , st_intersects((select polygon from location_table where location_name = 'A'), Point(ST_X(work_location), ST_Y(work_location))) as location_A
 from rent_table;
```

however I have millions of rows in rent_table therefore I do not want subquery in select statement to run for each of million rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
select
  r.*, 
  l.location_name
from rent r
left join location l on ST_CONTAINS(l.polygon, r.rent_location)
```